# how to fix unhandled error in formik (react native)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, formik, yup

I am using formik package and have error with post request. Also I am using yup for validation.

yup code part:

```
    const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
        donate: Yup.number().required().label("donate"),
    });
```

I am trying to create fake donation with following code:
Backend waiting from me `PATH PARAMETERS` which is `goalId` and `QUERY PARAMETERS` which is amount that I need to donate with form.

```
    const DonateScreen = ({route}) => {
 
    const goalId = route.params

    const handleSubmit = async (values) => {
    const {  ...restProps } = values;
    const payload = {
        donate: +restProps.donate,
    }

    try {
      const response = await axios.post(`donations/${goalId}?amount=${payload.donate}`, payload);
        await navigation.navigate("GoalsDescover");
    } catch (error) {
      const data = error.response.data;
      console.log(data);
    }
    };

    return (
    <Screen>
        <AppForm
        initialValues={{donate:""}}
        onSubmit={handleSubmit}
        validationSchema={validationSchema}
        >

      <View>
            <AppFormField placeholder="$" icon="credit-card" name="donate" />
            <SubmitButton title="Donate" /> 
      </View>
      </AppForm>
     </Screen>
    );
    };
```

but when I am submit donate button handlesumbit function not working and giving error like:

Warning: An unhandled error was caught from submitForm(), [TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_context.t0.response.data')]

Please help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: The error you are catching does not have a property called `response`...just do `console.log(error)` inside catch block and `console.log(response)` in place of `navigation` and show the output

Comment: I agree with @KartikeyVaish